# How can I push a .nupkg to a private NuGet source using dotnet?

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, nuget, aws-codebuild

I am creating an AWS CodePipeline, which references a CodeBuild project. This CodeBuild spins up an Ubuntu compute instance, and references a `buildspec.yml` file. On the post-build phase, I would like to push a `.nupkg` to a private NuGet source.

The following **Windows** command line logic works just fine:

```
> dotnet pack path/to/my/proj.csjproj
> nuget sources add -name MyPrivateRepo -source https://source -username u -password p
> nuget push path/to/my/newlypacked.nupkg -ApiKey key -Source https://source
```

As nuget.exe is not available on the Ubuntu instance (it can be if I install mono and do `mono nuget.exe ...` but this takes too long, even on the large build instance), **I want to use `dotnet nuget`. How would I go about achieving this?**

I understand that `dotnet nuget` is supposed to allow me to achieve the equivalent of what I showed above, but I find the documentation cryptic, and I'm struggling to find similar posts.

I've already tried installing `nuget`, and doing the following gymnastics,

```
> dotnet pack path/to/my/proj.csjproj
> apt-get install nuget -y
> mozroots --import --sync
> nuget sources add -name MyPrivateRepo -source https://source -username u -password p
> nuget push path/to/my/newlypacked.nupkg -ApiKey key -Source https://source
```

This results in the following:

```
Package Source with Name: MyPrivateRepo added successfully.

Pushing proj.nupkg to 'https://source'... 
  PUT https://source 
  BadRequest https://source 120ms 
400 (Bad Request - The package does not appear to be a valid ZIP archive (could not find a valid end of central directory record) (DevOps Activity ID: ...)) 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 400 (Bad Request - The package does not appear to be a valid ZIP archive (could not find a valid end of central directory record) (DevOps Activity ID: ...))
...
...
```

I confirmed that the `.nupkg` is indeed a valid NuGet package, and exists at the location I specified.

I also tried,

```
> dotnet pack path/to/my/proj.csjproj
> apt-get install nuget -y
> mozroots --import --sync
> nuget sources add -name MyPrivateRepo -source https://source -username u -password p
> dotnet nuget push path/to/my/newlypacked.nupkg -k key -s https://source
```

This results in the following:

```
Package Source with Name: MyPrivateRepo added successfully.
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://source. 
error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Could anyone please steer me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten this to work! Turns out the dotnet CLI looks for the NuGet config in a very particular location (although I don't see why the other locations I tried wouldn't work, after referring to their documentation): `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config`. Please note that this is CASE SENSITIVE!

In order to get the build pipeline to work, I have the following `buildspec.yml` structure:

```
...
> apt-get install nuget -y
> mozroots --import --sync
> nuget sources add -name MyPrivateRepo -source https://source -username u -password p
> mkdir -p ~/.nuget/NuGet && mv ~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config ~/.nuget/NuGet
> dotnet pack path/to/my/proj.csjproj
> dotnet nuget push path/to/my/newlypacked.nupkg -k key -s https://source
...
```

No mono installation required. I hope this helps!